# Translate CHAR_INFO.Attributes to ConsoleColor

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, console

In C# or VB.NET, I would like to translate the **Attributes** member of [CHAR_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/char-info-str) structure, to a [ConsoleColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor?view=netframework-4.7.2) for obtaining both the foreground color and background color.

This is the enumeration that I have declared using VB.NET:

```
<Flags>
Enum CharInfoAttributes As Short
    None = &H0S
    ForeColorBlue = &H1S
    ForeColorGreen = &H2S
    ForeColorRed = &H4S
    ForeColorIntensity = &H8S
    BackColorBlue = &H10S
    BackColorGreen = &H20S
    BackColorRed = &H40S
    BackColorIntensity = &H80S
    LeadingByte = &H100S
    TrailingByte = &H200S
    GridHorizontal = &H400S
    GridVerticalLeft = &H800S
    GridVerticalRight = &H1000S
    ReverseVideo = &H4000S
    Underscore = &H8000S
End Enum
```

For getting the forecolor I'm not sure if my solution is correct (I yet didn't tested all console colors) but it seem to work as expected with the colors that I tried...

```
Public Shared Function GetForeColor(attributes As CharInfoAttributes) As ConsoleColor

    If (attributes = CharInfoAttributes.None) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException(
                           paramName:=NameOf(attributes),
                           message:="Value does not contain forecolor information.")
    End If

    Dim value As CharInfoAttributes = attributes And
        Not CharInfoAttributes.BackColorBlue And
        Not CharInfoAttributes.BackColorGreen And
        Not CharInfoAttributes.BackColorRed And
        Not CharInfoAttributes.BackColorIntensity And
        Not CharInfoAttributes.GridHorizontal And
        Not CharInfoAttributes.GridVerticalLeft And
        Not CharInfoAttributes.GridVerticalRight And
        Not CharInfoAttributes.LeadingByte And
        Not CharInfoAttributes.TrailingByte And
        Not CharInfoAttributes.ReverseVideo And
        Not CharInfoAttributes.Underscore

    Return CType(value, ConsoleColor)

End Function
```

But I don't get the idea about how to retrieve the backcolor.

```
Public Shared Function GetBackColor(attributes As CharInfoAttributes) As ConsoleColor

    If (attributes = CharInfoAttributes.None) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException(
                           paramName:=NameOf(attributes),
                           message:="Value does not contain backcolor information.")
    End If

    ' ToDo...
    Return CType(value, ConsoleColor)

End Function
```

Comment: [ColorAttributeToConsoleColor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,7a88edaade340cdb)?

Comment: @TnTinMn It works as expected. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this solution thanks to @TnTinMn comment.

Enum definition:

```
<Flags>
Public Enum CharInfoAttributes As Short
    None = &H0S
    ForeColorBlue = &H1S
    ForeColorGreen = &H2S
    ForeColorRed = &H4S
    ForeColorIntensity = &H8S
    BackColorBlue = &H10S
    BackColorGreen = &H20S
    BackColorRed = &H40S
    BackColorIntensity = &H80S
    LeadingByte = &H100S
    TrailingByte = &H200S
    GridHorizontal = &H400S
    GridVerticalLeft = &H800S
    GridVerticalRight = &H1000S
    ReverseVideo = &H4000S
    Underscore = &H8000S
    ForeColorMask = &HFS
    BackColorMask = &HF0S
    ColorMask = &HFFS
End Enum
```

Functions:

```
Public Shared Function GetCharInfoAttributesForeColor(ByVal attributes As CharInfoAttributes) As ConsoleColor
    If ((attributes And CharInfoAttributes.ForeColorMask) <> 0) Then
        attributes = CType((CInt(attributes)) And Not CharInfoAttributes.BackColorMask, CharInfoAttributes)
    End If
    Return CType(attributes, ConsoleColor)
End Function

Public Shared Function GetCharInfoAttributesBackColor(ByVal attributes As CharInfoAttributes) As ConsoleColor
    ' https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,7a88edaade340cdb
    If ((attributes And CharInfoAttributes.BackColorMask) <> 0) Then
        ' Turn background colors into foreground colors.
        attributes = CType((CInt(attributes)) >> 4, CharInfoAttributes)
    End If
    Return CType(attributes, ConsoleColor)
End Function
```